# Why cant we measure the alleged curve of ball earth?

Tags: curvature, earth

Why can't we measure the alleged curvature of ball earth?

Answer (score 8):

Because you can - in a lot of different ways. Just not very easily by simply looking with your eyes while standing on its surface, as a ~1.70 m (on average) high critter versus an ~12 741 000 m (+/-1000 m) slightly bumpy spheroid of rock, so *literally* (as in truthfully literal-literal millions, and *not* figurative-literal) about 7.5 *million* times bigger than you (in *one* dimension only).

An apt analogy, with the right scale, would be an ant trying to use its eyes to figure out the whole shape of a very large mountain it is standing on. Some finesse is required to figure out what is actually going on - hence I don't blame you for your skepticism.

But that finesse has also been done, over and over - while unfortunately and especially recently, too many have tried to cast doubt on it, who are really psychologically manipulating you by appealing to that very strong (but *wrong*) sense you get from your "common sense" sense experience.

Comment: If the earth is a ball of its alleged circumference it should be sloping away from you in all directions at 8 inches per mile squared. You should be able to measure this across a body of water.

Comment: @Roguediabetic : What does "8 inches per mile squared" mean? I've heard this figure before in these debates but how is it calculated? I suspect that figure doesn't mean what they want you to think it means, and they have done some "sleight of hand" with the mathematics.

Comment: The figure is perhaps not wrong, but the calculation or how it's used are perhaps misleadingly presented. For one, "miles squared" is rather odd and I suspect this is some weird way of presenting curvature radius, which is $\frac{1}{R}$ - but to explain why this argument doesn't work would require a more thorough mathematical explanation: hint you can't just multiply the curvature radius by a distance and then say something with that number, you need more geometric theory than that.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer If you're curious, the leading order in the Taylor expansion for the distance you would have to go above a perfect sphere to draw a tangent line to a point a distance $d$ away is given by $d^2/2R$. For $d=1~\rm mi$, this is about $8$ inches, so flat-earthers just remember "8 inches per mile squared" as a rule of thumb. I highly doubt getting into a debate over this is going to lead anywhere productive, though.

Comment: @Chris : Thanks - wasn't expecting any useful debate here but I did want to know where that figure came from as I'd heard it cropping up elsewhere in similar discussions on other fora.

Comment: A simpler "proof"  " 1)The shadow of the earth also has a curvature reflecting that of  the earth , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_shadow   . Also remember , the ancient greeks had measured the perimeter of the earth 2000 + years ago https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes#Measurement_of_the_Earth's_circumference by using sticks and the highest point of the sun in different cities.

Comment: @Chris Ha, I've always wondered where they were pulling that fact from.  That totally makes sense though.  I'll have to do the math sometime and see how much that deviates from the real curvature.

Comment: And actually, then, you _would_ be able to see it. But you have to do the following: with a distance of one mile, 1. your object should be very tiny, like a pebble, 2. your eye needs to be within 8 inches of the ground. Seems challenging, right? At least, if you are not an eagle. What's the answer, then.? Simple. Get a lot bigger pebble and put a lot more miles between you and it. And, indeed, that is exactly what we see. Ships - much bigger "pebbles" - "go down" as they recede into the distance, exactly at the rate predicted by the curvature, yet

Comment: the flat Earthers contrive excuses for why this can't be the very proof that they seek. And to not understand that they have the wrong interpretation of the meaning of that figure, for which the correct interpretation is the one I just gave, and why it doesn't end up being as dramatic "looking" as they think it should be.